# jquery ajax is showing not found error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i am trying to use jquery ajax to pass data to server from client side.it should be super easy and it is.i added a static method in home.aspx and posted the data in there using ajax.but i have no idea why its always saying not found error.please any one can help me on that? here is my ajax code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#form1home a').click(function () {
           var position = $(this).parent().attr("id");
           $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: 'home.aspx/clickaction',
               contentType: 'application/json',
               dataType: 'json',
               data:  JSON.stringify({ "position":position }),
               success: function () {
               },
               error: function (request, status, error) {
                   alert(request+" "+error);
               }
           });

       });

   });
```

i am also giving the static method thati used in c#.

```
[WebMethod]
public static void clickaction(string position)
{
    DataBaseClass db = new DataBaseClass();
    string qry = "select * from cms_tbl where position='" + position + "' and shopid='" + HttpContext.Current.Session["shopid"].ToString() + "'";
    DataTable dt = db.ConnectDataBaseReturnDT(qry);

    if (dt.Rows[0]["type"].ToString() == "product")
    {
        string path = "product.aspx?id=" + dt.Rows[0]["items"].ToString() + "&shop=" + HttpContext.Current.Session["shopid"].ToString();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(path);
    }
    else if (dt.Rows[0]["type"].ToString() == "subcat")
    {
        string path = "productdisplay.aspx?id=" + dt.Rows[0]["items"].ToString() + "&sid=" + HttpContext.Current.Session["shopid"].ToString();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(path);
    }
    else if (dt.Rows[0]["type"].ToString() == "brand")
    {
        string path = "productdisplay.aspx?bid=" + dt.Rows[0]["items"].ToString() + "&sid=" + HttpContext.Current.Session["shopid"].ToString();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `home.aspx` in the same folder as the current page?

Comment: any error in Firebug?

Comment: It would be helpful to post the HTTP response you are getting, plus any relevant debugging or logging output.

Comment: no its not ,its in one level upper.i tried ../home.aspx and still trying i just put the wrong one here..the error is Not Found

Comment: Is your project a MVC web app??

Comment: [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms] thats in firebug

Comment: its not mvc its webform app

Comment: @LopaFarjanaRupa , can you try with full url to `home.aspx` in $.ajax instead of relative url?

Comment: i did but its still useless

Comment: could u remove  dataType: 'json', and try again

Comment: removing data type doesnt work as well

Answer (score 0):

the only thing I suggest you to check is the value of Position that you get from attribute of its parent

```
var position = $(this).parent().attr("id");
```

check it with an alert.